# Salvando stream em um arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo, struct, alocação, stream-de-arquivos

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao salvar o *struct,* a posição 1, acaba perdendo o valor de rua, cidade e estado.
Não entendo por que isso acontece se nas posições seguintes ele aloca de forma normal, e o código para fazer tal coisa é o mesmo.
O problema imagino eu está na função *salva_texto()*, por que se eu exibir os campos antes de salvar ele mostra normalmente, logo a alocação na inserção deve estar correta.

```
/*
 * File: main.c
 * Author: pmargreff
 *
 * Created on 6 de Novembro de 2014, 00:25
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 100

struct end {
    char nome[100];
    char rua[100];
    char cidade[100];
    char estado[100];
    unsigned long int cep;
} *info;

/*
 * struct para conseguir comparar
 * dois nomes em diversas funções
 */
struct compara {
    char nome[100];
} busca;
int flag = 0; // flag sinaliza é ativada quando o cadastro é acessado pela primeira vez
int tam = 0; //cria uma váriavel para que guardar o tamanho do vetor
void cria_lista(void);
void insere(void);
void apaga(void);
void pesquisa(void);
void imprime(void);
int menu(void);
int busca_nome(void);
void ler_string(char palavra[100], int tamanho);
void salva_texto(void);
void le_texto(void);

int main(void) {
    int escolha;
    cria_lista();
    for (;;) {
        escolha = menu();
        switch (escolha) {
            case 1: insere();
                break;
            case 2: apaga();
                break;
            case 3: imprime();
                break;
            case 4: pesquisa();
                break;
            case 5: salva_texto();
                break;
            case 6: le_texto();
                break;
            default: return 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
//aloca o suficiente para uma váriavel e armazena /0 na mesma

void cria_lista(void) {
    info = malloc(sizeof (struct end));
}

int menu(void) {
    int c = 0;
    do {
        printf("-- MENU:\n");
        printf("\t 1. Inserir um nome\n");
        printf("\t 2. Excluir um nome\n");
        printf("\t 3. Listar o arquivo\n");
        printf("\t 4. Pesquisar um nome\n");
        printf("\t 5. Salvar em arquivo\n");
        printf("\t 6. Abrir arquivo\n");
        printf("\t 7. Sair\n");
        printf("-- Digite sua escolha: ");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    } while (c <= 0 || c > 8);
    getchar();
    return c;
}

void ler_string(char palavra[100], int tamanho) {
    int i = 0;
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    while ((c != '\n') && (i < tamanho)) {
        palavra[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    palavra[i] = '\0';
    if (c != '\n') {
        c = getchar();
        while ((c != '\n') && (c != EOF)) {
            c = getchar();
        }
    }
}

void insere(void) {
    int aux;
    int posicao = tam;
    if (flag == 1) {
        printf("-- Registro %d:\n", posicao + 1);
    } else {
        printf("-- Registro %d:\n", posicao);
    }
    printf("\t Nome: ");
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    aux = busca_nome(); /*confere se já existe nome */
    if (aux != -1) { /*caso exista apenas volta ao menu anterior */
        return;
    }
    /*
     * quando a flag está ativa, aloca memória de acordo com o número de vezes que passa no vetor
     */
    if (flag == 1) {
        tam++;
        posicao = tam;
        info = realloc(info, tam + 1 * sizeof (struct end));
    }
    strcpy(info[posicao].nome, busca.nome);
    printf("\t Rua: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].rua, 40);
    printf("\t Cidade: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].cidade, 20);
    printf("\t Estado: ");
    ler_string(info[posicao].estado, 2);
    printf("\t CEP: ");
    scanf("%lu", &info[posicao].cep);
    flag = 1; //ativa a flag
}

/*
 * chama a funçao busca_nome que retorna o indice
 * para a variavel posicão que devera ser apagado
 * se nenhum nome igual for encontrado retorna -1
 */
void apaga(void) {
    int posicao;
    int confirma;
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    posicao = busca_nome();
    if (posicao >= 0 && posicao < tam) {
        printf("Você realmente deseja apagar %s?\n0-não\n1-sim", info[posicao].nome);
        scanf("%d", &confirma);
        if (confirma == 1) {
            info[posicao] = info[tam];
            tam--;
        }
    }
}

void imprime(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= tam; i++)
        if (info[i].nome[0] != '\0') {
            printf("-- Registro %d:\n", i);
            printf("\t Nome: %s", info[i].nome);
            printf("\t Rua: %s", info[i].rua);
            printf("\t Cidade: %s", info[i].cidade);
            printf("\t Estado: %s\n", info[i].estado);
            printf("\t CEP: %lu\n", info[i].cep);
        }
}

/*
 * função que faz a busca de um nome no programa
 * le o nome que está localizado na struct busca.nome
 * e retorna o indice se encontrar nome igual ou
 * -1 se não encontrar nome como aquele
 */
int busca_nome(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= tam; i++) {
        if (strcmp(busca.nome, info[i].nome) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

/* função para procurar e exibir apenas o nome desejado
 * chama o função busca_nome que devolve o indice para
 * a variavel i se for válido e se não existir devolve
 * menos um, o a exibição só é feita quando o indice é
 * diferente de menos um e menor que o máximo pré estabelecido
 */
void pesquisa(void) {
    int i;
    ler_string(busca.nome, 30);
    i = busca_nome();
    if (i >= 0 && i <= tam) {
        printf("-- Registro %d:\n", i);
        printf("\t Nome: %s", info[i].nome);
        printf("\t Rua: %s", info[i].rua);
        printf("\t Cidade: %s", info[i].cidade);
        printf("\t Estado: %s\n", info[i].estado);
        printf("\t CEP: %lu\n", info[i].cep);
    } else {
        printf("Nome não encontrado na lista!! \n\n");
    }
}

/*
void salva_bin(void) {
FILE *arquivo;
int i;
arquivo = fopen("dados.bin", "w");
for (i = 0; i <= tam; i++) {
fwrite(&i, sizeof (int), 1, arquivo);
fwrite(&info[i], sizeof (struct end), 1, arquivo);
}
//fwrite(&info, MAX*sizeof(struct end), 1, arquivo);
fclose(arquivo);
}
void abre_arq(void) {
FILE *arquivo;
int i;
arquivo = fopen("dados.bin", "r");
while (!feof(arquivo)) {
fread(&i, sizeof (int), 1, arquivo);
fread(&info[i], sizeof (struct end), 1, arquivo);
}
tam = i;
//fread(&info, MAX*sizeof(struct end), 1, arquivo);
fclose(arquivo);
}
 */
void salva_texto() {
    FILE *arquivo;
    int i;
    arquivo = fopen("dados.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i <= tam; i++) {
        fprintf(arquivo, "%d\n", i);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", info[i].nome);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", info[i].rua);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", info[i].cidade);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%s\n", info[i].estado);
        fprintf(arquivo, "%lu\n", info[i].cep);
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
}

void le_texto() {
    int flag = 0;
    FILE *arquivo;
    int i;
    free(info);
    info = malloc(sizeof (struct end));
    arquivo = fopen("dados.txt", "r");
    tam = 0;
    while (!feof(arquivo)) {
        if (flag != 0)
            tam++;
        info = realloc(info, tam + 1 * sizeof (struct end));
        fscanf(arquivo, "%d", &i);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%[^\n]%*c", info[i].nome);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%[^\n]%*c", info[i].rua);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%[^\n]%*c", info[i].cidade);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%[^\n]%*c", info[i].estado);
        fscanf(arquivo, "%lu", &info[i].cep);
        flag = 1; //altera a flag para na próxima vez começar a alocação de memória
    }
    fclose(arquivo);
    tam = i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    info = realloc(info, (tam + 1) * sizeof (struct end));
    //                   ^       ^
```

Mas vais desperdicar memoria para 1 objecto.

Como incrementas o `tam` antes do `realloc` não precisas de somar `1`.
Não te esqueças que num array (ou espaço de alocação dinâmica) com espaço para três elementos, esses elementos têm os indices `0`, `1`, e `2`.

Comment: Porém essa função não altera na escrita do arquivo, onde creio que seja o erro.

Comment: Se mandas o computador aceder a dados num sitio que "não existe" e mandas imprimir esses dados, e ele imprime coisas sem sentido .... o problema está na impressão ou no acesso aos dados????

Comment: é isso que não entendo, por que quando acesso os dados um número indeterminado de vezes, ele exibe, se mando ele fazer isso, depois de salvar ele não exibe, porém no salvar ele apenas passa a stream para um arquivo, e não altera a mesma. Deveria alterar apenas na função lê texto...